# C3PO connection pooling - connections not being released

Tags: java, spring, connection-pooling

I have a web application running under Tomcat 7 using Spring with `c3po` as the connection pool manager. I have also used `dbcp` and have the same result.

I initiate a long running single threaded process which makes a large number of database calls using `jdbcTemplate.update()`, etc,  in various `dao`'s.  As each of these updates is simple and independent, no transaction manager is being used.

For some reason, I am running out of connections. What appears to be happening is that each `dao` is holding onto its own connection and not returning it to the pool.

Is this normal behaviour? I had expected that the connection was tied to the `jdbcTemplate.update()` and released back as soon as this had finished.

...

In the context file...

```
<bean id="enquiryDataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${enquiry.drivername}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${enquiry.jdbc}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${enquiry.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${enquiry.password}"/>

        <property name="maxWait" value="30000"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="50"/>
</bean>
```

In a typical dao constructor...

```
@Autowired
public XXXCountryDao(@Qualifier("enquiryDataSource") DataSource dataSource,
                       @Qualifier("sqlUpdaterFactoryImpl") SqlUpdaterFactory sqlUpdaterFactory, @Qualifier("sqlFormatterFactoryImpl") SqlFormatterFactory sqlFormatterFactory) {

    super("Country", dataSource, sqlUpdaterFactory, sqlFormatterFactory);
    // ...other constructor stuff

}
```

All dao's inherit from...

```
public abstract class AbstractFileProcessorDao<ImportRecType, QueryRecType> extends JdbcDaoSupport {

// ...

}
```

In a typical dao method...

```
protected boolean runUpdateToSqlDatabase(Map<String, Object> values, Map<String, Object> whereValues) {
    if (values.isEmpty())
        return true;

    String sql = updateUpdaterServer.getSql(values, whereValues);

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
        logger.debug("Server SQL -> " + sql);

    getJdbcTemplate().update(sql);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: To have connection release etc. you need a transaction manager and you really should have managed transactions even if your updates are simple. It isn't the database layer that should be transactional but your service layer that should drive the transactions.

Comment: OK. I'll try that. However, I don't understand why this should be the case. Surely a call to the update() method is effectively a transaction in itself?

Comment: @M.Deinum *you need a transaction manager* - your comment does not make sense in relation to OP's problem. If connections are not released (i.e. returned back to pool), the problem must be somewhere in the code. Having TX manager is a suggestion for a different topic. JdbcTemplate does not require active transaction to work properly.

Comment: Pavel - Did you mean I don't need a transaction manager or I do?

Comment: You should use TX management, but not having it can not cause your problem. Btw. are you calling somewhere http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection%28%29 in your code manually?

Comment: So am I right in my assertion that jdbcTemplate.update() should release the connection?

Comment: @PavelHoral true, however half-backed tx setup is never a good thing. Next to that he should really use one together with proper setup as that will allow connection reuse, instead of a single connection per query. Which should speedup his execution time.

Comment: @Mark Yes... https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/1204d2aef4afdefb4ba73c86565aab3f5b2a6931/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L351

Comment: @M.Deinum connections are reused automatically when pooling (like DBCP or C3PO) is in game. But I understand your point.

Comment: Each and every call uses Spring's jdbcTemplate.update(), delete() execute(), etc.  There are no native jdbc calls

Comment: Then "there is something rotten" in there. Please confirm, that you are not using more than one thread (as stated in the question), nor running your application multiple times. Also confirm what your problem "connections not being released" / "running out of connections" exactly means (you get error; connections are not closed - which is correct behavior, ...).

Comment: Trust me I know how a connection pool, is supposed to, work. But retrieving a connection each time might be overkill especially if validation queries etc. are set on the pool. So yes a connection is reused but a single connection for the whole session is, generally, always faster.

Comment: Please add some code and configuration.

Comment: To clarify then - the long running process is initiated by calling a REST service. This creates and launches a single thread and returns. This thread performs all the processing, potentially hundreds of thousands of updates across multiple dao's.

Comment: You have to close your session/entitymanager to release connection.\

Comment: No. As an example, I can run a part of the process which uses just a single dao and I can see the connection being used. If I run the same again, it re-uses the same connection. So far, so good. If I then, separately, run a different part of the process, it creates a second connection, and if I re-run this it reuses this connection. So my assumption is that the connection seems to be tied to the calling class in some way.

Comment: All dao's extend an abstract class which extends JdbcDaoSupport.

By exception, do you mean the error I eventually get if I don't make available enough connections to the pool? If so, it will eventually lock up in one of the dao's until the wait timeout is reached at which point it throws an exception (I can get the details of this if it is important)

Comment: @Mark it was just important to verify what you wrote. Information in the comment is enough. I've learned on SO to double check every statement rather than trying to find solution to a completely different problem :).

Comment: The code and information you have posted seems completely fine to me. So instead of providing an actual answer, I suggest to you to run in DEBUG mode. When the exception occurs, double check active threads in your JVM (there might be some asynchronous processing which you are not aware of). If this does not help, then you can wrap DataSource instance in a wrapper, which will log every `getConnection` call (you might find some unexpected calls there...). You can also put breakpoint inside `Connection#close` to see, that JdbcTemplate is really releasing the connection (which it should).Good luck

Comment: @Pavel, I appreciate all your help and will keep you posted on the outcome!

Comment: @Pavel - _Btw. are you calling somewhere docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/… in your code manually?_

The answer is yes! I might add, it wasn't me! Removing this, which was in the base class for all dao's, resolved the problem.

If you want to add a one-liner response, I'll accept the answer. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your application for "rogue" calls to [`DataSource#getConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection%28%29) (you can use your IDE to search for method references). Connection leaks are usually caused by obtaining a connection which is then never closed via [`Connection#close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close%28%29).

When working with Spring's `JdbcTemplate` all JDBC resource handling (opening / closing connections, statements, result sets) is done automatically. But with legacy code you never know.